# Issue using Quarkus with Kogito

Tags: swagger-ui, quarkus, bpmn, kogito

I'm trying to run a Qurkus application with a simple *kogito bpmn flow*, after trying lot of things, the final version of my `pom.xml` is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.kogito</groupId>
  <artifactId>test-kogito</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.release>17</maven.compiler.release>
    <quarkus.platform.artifact-id>quarkus-bom</quarkus.platform.artifact-id>
    <quarkus.platform.group-id>io.quarkus.platform</quarkus.platform.group-id>
    <quarkus.platform.version>2.7.0.Final</quarkus.platform.version> <!-- Updated Quarkus version -->
  </properties>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
        <artifactId>${quarkus.platform.artifact-id}</artifactId>
        <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- Dependencia de Kogito -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-kogito</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-openapi</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>build</goal>
              <goal>generate-code</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>native</id>
      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>native</name>
        </property>
      </activation>
      <properties>
        <quarkus.package.type>native</quarkus.package.type>
      </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

The project runs properly but when I try to access `localhost:8080/swagger-ui/` I get a *404-Error*, so I think kogito is not deploying its swagger with the bpmn process.

Logs, when starting *quarkus application*:

```
__  ____  __  _____   ___  __ ____  ______ 
 --/ __ \/ / / / _ | / _ \/ //_/ / / / __/ 
 -/ /_/ / /_/ / __ |/ , _/ ,< / /_/ /\ \   
--\___\_\____/_/ |_/_/|_/_/|_|\____/___/   
2024-03-26 16:55:20,986 INFO  [io.quarkus] (Quarkus Main Thread) test-kogito 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT on JVM (powered by Quarkus 2.7.0.Final) started in 3.795s. Listening on: http://localhost:8080
2024-03-26 16:55:20,987 INFO  [io.quarkus] (Quarkus Main Thread) Profile dev activated. Live Coding activated.
2024-03-26 16:55:20,987 INFO  [io.quarkus] (Quarkus Main Thread) Installed features: [cdi, kogito, resteasy-jackson, smallrye-context-propagation, smallrye-openapi, swagger-ui, vertx]
```

Also when I click on the localhost path the logs change and then this appears:

```
2024-03-26 16:56:08,577 INFO  [io.qua.dep.dev.RuntimeUpdatesProcessor] (vert.x-worker-thread-0) Restarting quarkus due to changes in ProjectModel.class, Application$Processes.class, SessionRuleUnit_defaultStatelessKieSession.class, ApplicationConfig.class, Application$DecisionModels.class, Application.class, ApplicationProcesses.class, Application$RuleUnits.class, ProjectRuntime.class, SessionRuleUnit_defaultKieSession.class.
2024-03-26 16:56:08,593 INFO  [io.quarkus] (Quarkus Main Thread) test-kogito stopped in 0.015s
2024-03-26 16:56:08,639 WARN  [io.qua.dep.bui.CapabilityBuildItem] (build-5) An instance of io.quarkus.deployment.builditem.CapabilityBuildItem was created using a deprecated constructor by io.quarkus.kogito.deployment.KogitoAssetsProcessor to provide capability 'io.quarkus.kogito'. Please report this issue to the extension maintainers to fix it in the future releases.
2024-03-26 16:56:08,646 WARN  [io.qua.dep.ste.CapabilityAggregationStep] (build-27) The following capabilities were found to be missing from the processed extension descriptors:
 - io.quarkus.kogito provided by io.quarkus.kogito.deployment.KogitoAssetsProcessor
Please report this issue to the extension maintainers to get it fixed in the future releases.
__  ____  __  _____   ___  __ ____  ______ 
 --/ __ \/ / / / _ | / _ \/ //_/ / / / __/ 
 -/ /_/ / /_/ / __ |/ , _/ ,< / /_/ /\ \   
--\___\_\____/_/ |_/_/|_/_/|_|\____/___/   
2024-03-26 16:56:08,786 INFO  [io.quarkus] (Quarkus Main Thread) test-kogito 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT on JVM (powered by Quarkus 2.7.0.Final) started in 0.190s. Listening on: http://localhost:8080
2024-03-26 16:56:08,787 INFO  [io.quarkus] (Quarkus Main Thread) Profile dev activated. Live Coding activated.
2024-03-26 16:56:08,787 INFO  [io.quarkus] (Quarkus Main Thread) Installed features: [cdi, kogito, resteasy-jackson, smallrye-context-propagation, smallrye-openapi, swagger-ui, vertx]
2024-03-26 16:56:08,787 INFO  [io.qua.dep.dev.RuntimeUpdatesProcessor] (vert.x-worker-thread-0) Live reload total time: 0.224s
```

*I want to execute a quarkus appliaction implementing a bpmn flow using kogito.*

Comment: "such as http://localhost:8080/q/swagger-ui or http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html" says [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_decision_manager/7.11/html/getting_started_with_red_hat_decision_manager/proc-kogito-microservice-interacting-app_getting-started-kogito-microservices) also you can check [dev-ui](https://quarkus.io/guides/dev-ui)